# Can I query close vote reviews on data?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Given the recently increasing number of votes in the close vote review queue, I thought I'd put together [a little query on data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126894/close-votes-cast-per-day).

My intention was to compare the number of close votes being cast per day with the number of reviews on close votes being processed per day, to see how far behind we're falling every day at the current pace.

I got the close votes cast per day fine, but I can't find the table where close vote reviews are stored.

Is this data available on the data explorer? If so, where is it? If not, could it be made available?

Comment: **+1** Yes *please*! (Also, if you return a date then a number, instead of number then date, I think Data Explorer graphs it for you.)

Comment: @michaelb958 I never knew that - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible since the addition of the ReviewTasks tables. Also notice that the Votes table doesn't hold much data after june 2013. Instead use the PostHistory table.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201918/close-votes-being-cast-per-day-versus-reviews-on-close-votes#graph) answers your question I believe:

```
-- our date range
;with main as (
select distinct 
convert(date,creationdate) as [Date]
from reviewtaskresults
) 
-- our review tasks
, rvc as (
select convert(date,creationdate) as [Date]
      , count(*) as [cnt]
from reviewtaskresults
where ReviewTaskResultTypeId = 6 -- close
group by convert(date,creationdate)
)
-- our closed posts
, pc as (
select convert(date,creationdate) as [Date]
, count(*) as cnt
from posthistory
where posthistorytypeid = 10 -- post closed
group by convert(date,creationdate)
)
-- outer join the whole bups
select main.[date]
    , rvc.cnt as [Close Review Tasks]
    , pc.cnt as [Posts Closed]
from main
left outer  join rvc on rvc.[date] = main.[date]
left outer join pc on pc.[date] = main.[date]
order by main.[date]
```

And the graph that is the result:

[image: close votes vs close reviews]

Comment: Lovely! Thanks a lot.