# Add review data to SEDE

Tags: feature-request, review, data-explorer

As you may or may not be aware, Stack Overflow's close vote review queue [is growing out of control](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183840/223030). I felt like graphing the progress of the queue historically, and attempted to persuade the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to give me the data. I was, however, stymied by the lack of a **Reviews** table. The current SEDE query is a 32-line monster with three CTEs and six `INNER JOIN`s - which still can't account for [expired close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/223030) or [deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462/223030) due to limitations of SEDE.

Seeing as expired close votes [will not be added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121160/223030), and metadata on deleted posts has been heavily protested, I would like to propose that some data on reviews (of all types, because why not) be added to SEDE. I'm not asking for much - something like the following:

```
Id INT NOT NULL,
PostId INT,
ReviewTypeId TINYINT NOT NULL,
CreationDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
CompletionDate DATETIME,
PossibleDuplicateId INT,
SuggestedEditId INT,
IsAudit BIT
```

(As suggested by @Rachel on the deleted-questions-metadata question, maybe null out `PostId` for deleted posts.)

Even this minimal data (it doesn't include reviewer stats or individual review timestamps) would allow my use case:

```
WITH CreatedCVReviews(CreationDate, CreationCount) AS (
  SELECT CAST(CreationDate AS DATE), COUNT(*)
  FROM Reviews
  WHERE ReviewTypeId = 5 -- or whatever ID
  GROUP BY CAST(CreationDate AS DATE)
), CompletedCVReviews(CompletionDate, CompletionCount) AS (
  SELECT CAST(CompletionDate AS DATE), COUNT(*)
  FROM Reviews
  WHERE ReviewTypeId = 5
  GROUP BY CAST(CompletionDate AS DATE)
)
SELECT
  Cr.CreationDate AS [Date],
  Cr.CreationCount - Co.CompletionCount AS [Net Tasks Added]
FROM CreatedCVReviews AS Cr
INNER JOIN CompletedCVReviews AS Co
  ON Cr.CreationDate = Co.CompletionDate
ORDER BY Cr.CreationDate
```

## Other related posts

[An answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164892/223030) to [Stack Exchange Table Structure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164889/223030) postulates that tables with review data *may* be added in future. That was eight months ago.

The question [Can I query close vote reviews on data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191413/223030) is a possible duplicate from last month. I feel that the question you're reading now better presents the evidence; posting this as an answer to the possidupe didn't feel right, and editing the possidupe with this amount of new stuff is just plain frowned upon. (If you disagree, vote <kbd>it is a duplicate...</kbd> as desired.)

Comment: _"but that was 8 months ago"_ I'd give it 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's about 2 months, tops.

Comment: @michaelb958 [not necessarily so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog "that's a meme meaning wait can be indefinitely long")

Comment: Perhaps if they lowered the rep needed to review those...  You can't find a First Post or Late Answer review to be had, because people are sitting at their keyboard hitting the <refresh> key waiting to get one.

Comment: @gnat I know. I was just interpreting it literally, for whatever reason.