# Can't get Data Explorer results to agree with StackOverflow close vote queue size

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close, data-explorer

I'm messing around with Data Explorer and having some trouble getting results that match the Stack Overflow close vote queue size displayed on /review.

The review page says the current queue size is ~94.9k.

In Data Explorer, [here is a query to show distribution of close vote counts for all questions that are not already closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149240/close-vote-count-distribution?opt.textResults=true):

```
CloseVotes Frequency 
---------- --------- 
1          29959     
2          15805     
3          7691      
4          1611      
5          39
```

And, [here is a similar query, but for all posts, even already closed ones](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149241/close-vote-count-distribution?opt.textResults=true):

```
CloseVotes Frequency 
---------- --------- 
1          93967     
2          47332     
3          27496     
4          17330     
5          184734
```

My expectation is that the sum of 1-4 in the first query (i.e. the number of open questions with less than 5 close votes) would be 94.9k -- the size of the queue. It's actually 55,066.

Obviously I've got something wrong here, but I'm not sure what:

- I have the wrong idea of what the close queue is, or
- I made a mistake in my queries (e.g. does a null CloseDate mean the post is open?), or
- Maybe I didn't make a mistake and the /review queue size is incorrect, but I doubt it.

What is going on?

Also, I have a couple other incidental questions:

- How are there 39 questions with 5 close votes but that aren't closed?
- [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/149242) shows 240470 closed questions, but the difference in totals between the above to queries is 315754. How is that possible?

Comment: I want to add a few more things (sorry I hope the very last question about the 240470 vs 315754 makes sense, I realize it's underexplained) but my laptop battery *strongly* disagrees.

Comment: Questions with high votes need more close votes AFAIK.

Comment: The review queue sometimes also shows posts which were flagged by some other users(?). I've seen quite a few of such questions.

Comment: Yes, some flags put questions up for review.

Comment: If it helps anyone, [I requested that actual review tasks be added to the DE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196673/223030).

Comment: So, based on the comments here, the reason that I am seeing less in my query than in reality is because I am not including questions that are flagged but have 0 close votes so far. Am I understanding that correctly? I always thought flagging a question to be closed sent the question to a special moderator review queue instead of the community close review queue -- is that not the case?

Comment: @JasonC those go to the queue, yes - under certain circumstances they go to Moderators IIRC.  There's simply too much volume for them all to go straight to the mods.

Comment: The 39 questions with 5 votes are put `on hold` i think

Comment: The data explorer is missing some of the close vote data right now since it's stored in a different table. Shog9 has a feature-request up to address this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/please-add-close-flags-duplicate-links-and-review-data-to-the-public-data-dump.