# Allow us to see close vote history on another user's profile for closed questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, api

### Background

There was a meta question over at [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/can-we-eliminate-the-close-reason-primarily-opinion-based) which had me wading through a lot of closed questions. Every closed question has a nice box like this that shows who closed it:

[image: closed question banner]

After a few dozen questions, I saw clear trends on how people were voting, and thought to myself, *"Wouldn't it be nice to know who the most prolific closers are, and for what reasons?"*

### Problem

Thinking logically, I assumed that since the information was displayed publicly on all closed posts, there must be some hidden corner of the user profile that displays this sort of info.

Nope.

Well, then there must be some sort of information in the API at least to retrieve this, right?

Nope.

### Solution

This information is already available, just tedious to compile. There shouldn't be any issue with making it more accessible.

For questions which are:

1. Already closed
2. Voted on either directly on the question or through the queue

The 'votes' in the profile page for 'closure' should show the questions in question:

> [image: Close Summary]

Additionally, there should be an additional field in the API that lets us track who voted on closed questions (just add an additional field linked with `shallow_user` that provides the names of the 5 people who voted to close, and the timing of it).

Comment: This does not exactly what you suggest and only catches the close/reopen votes stated in the review queue if I understand this correctly, but you can go to the user profile, and select Reviews from the Activity tab.

Comment: @Dilaton, yep, the issue is that for smaller beta sites, a large portion of the close votes do not come from the review queue (when you have 5-10 questions a day, the more frequent users, especially the active close-voters, will usually read every question and cast their votes directly).

Comment: It seems perfectly logical to display who closed a question while **not** displaying the entire history of close votes for a user. I don't really see the need for the latter, while the prior gives a bit of accountability. But I support [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/please-add-close-flags-duplicate-links-and-review-data-to-the-public-data-dump) because it would allow us to (easily) run some much-needed statistics on close-voting.

Comment: @Dukeling, I'm a bit confused. All I want is the 'display who closed a question' in one location, rather than having to look at each closed question and taking notes on who closed which. The information is available (I am not asking for anything that can't already be discovered), it is just not accessible. I am not asking for a close vote history on questions that are not yet closed.

Comment: @Dukeling, I don't think we're talking about the same thing. I do not need review queue data (which is currently accessible), and I don't need it to be in the data dump (that currently doesn't include beta sites, which is what I want this for). I want closed questions which list people's names to be accessible from the person's profile page and in the API (`/users/close-votes/` maybe?).

Comment: Sorry, seems I greatly misread the linked request (thought it was asking to make the user IDs public) (which I'd much prefer to this, to be able to generate some stats, as noted above).