# How do I know the list of questions closed by me?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just want to see the list of questions closed by me in [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) and also want to see which are all not closed, the one which I proposed as first person(meaning I'm the first person to close the question).

Comment: Closest thing is probably the closure section of the votes tab in your profile. Although that doesn't differentiate on if they ultimately are closed

Comment: Sounds like a job for SEDE, although I can't believe such a query doesn't already exist

Comment: @RichardTingle: why do you prefer answering as a comment instead that answering as an answer?

Comment: @Sam Because its not strickly speaking an answer. Its helpful, but it doesn't fully give what Bala wants

Comment: @RichardTingle: ok, thanks. I'm trying to better understand how meta works.

Comment: @Sam - Same applies to other SE sites as well. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't think it's possible, close user IDs aren't exposed through SEDE. Happy to be wrong though :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I know they weren't there a few months ago, but I thought they were added (or maybe they are only considering it).  It's not like close votes are private.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I'm wrong, they aren't there yet [Please add close flags, duplicate links and review data to the public data dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/please-add-close-flags-duplicate-links-and-review-data-to-the-public-data-dump)