# Number of delete and close votes

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I have seen some people mentioning how many close votes they have cast so far. I was trying to figure my stats correspondingly, but I have not found a way of doing that for my own account.

Currently, if I go to the votes tab on my profile page, and then close or delete, I see some numbers, but it does not show "deleted" posts, so one day I can potentially get the number smaller there than the day before.

Is it possible to get these numbers for your own account as a non-moderator? Perhaps the people, telling me about their stats, meant how many reviews they have done in the close vote review queue?

(I personally believe this could be a useful information, at least for the moderator election - e.g. by the system only in that case, and automatically - in the future to expose for even more accurate assessment)

Comment: You do know close vote stats are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)? Simarly for the other queues. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @rene: that is the stats for close vote reviews, not close votes; it will also incorporate the "Leave open" decisions, and it will not contain close vote casts outside the review process, e.g. through normal closure vote or the moderation tools.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the obvious :-)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian You are asking for several impossible things at once. Delete votes in SEDE are [anonymized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/251274), they do not have UserId. Also, votes related to deleted content are not in SEDE at all, so the only delete votes there are those not (yet) successful. As for close votes, after 2013-06-25 refactoring they are [not in SEDE at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208806/251274). And those cast prior to 2013-06-25 are anonymized.