# What is CompletedByReviewTaskId in the ReviewTasks table?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump

Could someone clarify what is the field "CompletedByReviewTaskId" in the "ReviewTasks" table in the stackexchange schema? Is this the userId of the user who completed the review?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation of the scheme is discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208806/please-add-close-flags-duplicate-links-and-review-data-to-the-public-data-dump/227468#227468), and from an [example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179781/review-tasks-by-result) on that page, we can determine that it is the review action that caused the review task to be completed.

So if there's a review task for a suggested edit, and 3 people need to approve it, the *action* of the third person approving it will be in the `CompletedByReviewTaskId` field.