# Why aren't files for review tasks and suggested edits or the votes on them in the data-dump?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, data-dump

In the data base schema ([Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)), there are tables called ReviewTasks, ReviewTaskResults, SuggestedEdits, and SuggestedEditVotes but there are no corresponding files on https://archive.org/details/stackexchange.

Comment: Related: [Please add close flags, duplicate links and review data to the public data dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208806)

Comment: The answer is *probably* lack of demand vs. increased data dump size, but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reasons are given by [Tim Stone in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243463/why-arent-files-for-review-tasks-and-suggested-edits-or-the-votes-on-them-in-th#comment795803_243463) and [Shog9 in his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214858/158100):

- lack of demand (on this question and  related ones)
- significant rise in the size of the data dump (for Stack Overflow alone it is over 40GB)

With a clear and reasonable use case this request might be revisited but until that moment you have to rely on the weekly updates of those tables in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

I've made the tablenames that can be found in the Data Dump *italic* in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100)