# Is the dump of the database behind stack exchange data explorer available?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

The database on which the SEDE runs seems to be much more complete with [several additional tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) than the dataset available as part of the public data dump through [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Some of the additional tables include CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes table, many more PostHistoryTypeId in the PostHistory table, to name just a few.

Is it possible to make the dump of the SEDE database publicly available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Shog9 explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214858/1438) the absense of the `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes` table: the close flag data is very temporal and doesn't give a complete picture. As such, it's not worth adding to an already large data dump for archive.

In fact, the size of the data dump precludes us from making regular copies of *all* SEDE data. For the vast majority of research and for the [primary goal of the dump](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), the excluded metadata is of little value. Expanding the size of the data (for *all* researchers) without providing significant value does not seem like the best idea.

For the most part, we add data to SEDE first and add it to the dump if it seems it could be put to good use by future researchers. Do you have a specific need for the missing data that can't be satisfied by running a query on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?